# Launching landscape app according to iOS human interface guidelines

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

As per the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/StartingStopping.html), when the device is held in portrait mode, a landscape app should always launch orientated with the home button on the right.

**However, I cannot make the launch screen behave to match this expectation.** So my best efforts will result in a vertical flip as the app transitions from launch screen to the app window.

I looked at some apps and not everyone honours this guideline, but others do, so this issue is definitely solvable. So the behaviour I'm looking for, is to have Landscape-Left orientation "temporarily disabled" during launch, if and only if we're in portrait mode.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered the solution:
When a landscape-only app is launched in portrait mode, the orientation (i.e. whether it will be left or right) will be selected based on the **ordering of entries** under the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations node in the app plist file.

So the solution was the change item order from the xcode-generated

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

to

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
</array>
```